# Java - Check vm variables from inside eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables, virtual-machine

Is there a way to look at the environment variables used for the Java virtual machine, from an instance of Eclipse?

To put it another way, how can I check which environment variables are being used by this instance of Eclipse?

I've got a portable setup and I'd like to see everything is working as I expect...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the Eclipse menu, click: Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details

The configurations tab contains everything that your environment 'knows' about.

Answer (score 2):

This varies from system to system though. Basically [System.getenv()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) returns all the environment property in a Map.

This should get you what you want:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> environment = System.getenv();
            for (String env: environment.keySet()) {
                System.out.format("%s=%s%n", env, environment.get(env));
            }

    }
```

This example code was adapted from [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html).

Comment: So it does. Cool beans man!  Gonna float this for a little while to see if anything incrementally nifty comes out, but you're in the lead.

Comment: very cool thing to know about but sgibly's answer is more along the lines of what I was looking for.  Thanks though!  I wish I could accept two answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just searching the eclipse help? That is usually pretty helpful

Comment: Spent some time there, and although it mentions environment variables several times, they're all related to plugins, not the main program.  Google apparently is confused also.